# Two titles on a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, titles

I am presenting two papers at once and I'd like to put both titles on the same page. The papers have different sets of authors too, so I'd like to display that.

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you're going to discuss two articles, but that doesn't mean you have to give two titles to your presentation (this is rather unusual). Have you considered using *one* common descriptive title for the presentation, and then in the body dedicate one or two frames to the articles and their authors?

Comment: I understand it's unusual but in my situation it seems appropriate.  The first paper is a coauthored paper that builds a lot that is required to understand the second, sole-authored, paper. This is for a job talk, so I want to emphasize my contribution. I am part of both, but my contribution in the second is much more evident. I think that putting either title alone in the beginning would be misleading in some way; I wouldn't know who should be included as an author.

Thanks for the welcome :)